# I am trying to run jobs -l command in my for loop but it is just displaying the the parameter not the actual values

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I am trying to run a script through for loop in the loop i am giving the jobs -l command after the each process started and then I am capturing into the log, it is displaying the just the execution command with the parameters not actual parameter values, is there a way to capture the including the actual parameters into the log.

```
for table_name in `cat exec.lst`
    ./abc.sh ${table_name} 1>&2 2>>table_name.log &

jobs -l | grep abc.sh > ${LOG_DIR}/tables_status.list
```

output of the jobs -l command:

```
[1]10283 Done ./abc.sh ${table_name} 1>&2 2>>${LOG_DIR}/${table_name}.log
[2]10323 Done ./abc.sh ${table_name} 1>&2 2>>${LOG_DIR}/${table_name}.log
[3]10362 Done ./abc.sh ${table_name} 1>&2 2>>${LOG_DIR}/${table_name}.log            
[4]10403 Done ./abc.sh ${table_name} 1>&2 2>>${LOG_DIR}/${table_name}.log              
[5]10443 Done ./abc.sh ${table_name} 1>&2 2>>${LOG_DIR}/${table_name}.log
```

is there any other way which i can get the information of the actual table_name.

expected output:

```
[1]10283 Done ./abc.sh table1 1>&2 2>>${LOG_DIR}/table1.log
[2]10323 Done ./abc.sh table2 1>&2 2>>${LOG_DIR}/table2.log
[3]10362 Done ./abc.sh table3 1>&2 2>>${LOG_DIR}/table3.log               
[4]10403 Done ./abc.sh table4 1>&2 2>>${LOG_DIR}/table4.log                  
[5]10443 Done ./abc.sh table5 1>&2 2>>${LOG_DIR}/table5.log
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, i'm not sure

```
./abc.sh ${table_name} 2>&1 >> {table_name}.log &
```